# Field of Deformation

Tags: mathematical-modeling, classical-mechanics

Let $y(x)$ be a field of deformation s.t.
$$ || y(x_1) - y(x_2) || = ||x_1 - x_2 || \ \  \forall x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb R^d$$

Can anybody show me why $y(x) = Qx + a$ holds true for appropriate $ Q \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$ and $a \in \mathbb R^d$ ?

Comment: Hint. See the concept for Fréchet derivative. I assume that the question is about $\vert\vert y(x_1)-y(x_2)\vert\vert = $

Comment: [This](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/isometryRn.pdf) might be helpful for you.

Comment: @hypernova yeah but in your link, I don't see that there is an assumption for h(x) (which is, in my example, y(x) ).

Comment: @DMan: A field deformation is a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$. It tells where the point, initially at $x$, is located after deformation.

Comment: @hypernova So the solution is in fact that $y: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ where $|| (x_1, ..., x_d) || = \sqrt{x_1^2 + ... + x_d^2}$ ?

Comment: @DMan: Er... This is the definition of the norm. I am afraid you need to go through this 18-page document, at least from the very beginning to page 7. The key step is proven until Theorem 4.1 at the end of page 6, while the answer to your question follows immediately in Theorem 4.2 on page 7. Your question is not the one that can be easily answered within a few sentences, and that is why a complete proof costs roughly 6 pages in that document.

Comment: @hypernova All right thanks a lot for the link and the comments! I'll read the document afterwards :-)

Comment: @DMan: Sure! No problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

If

$$ || y(x_1) - y(x_2) || = ||x_1 - x_2 || \ \  \forall x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb R^d$$

then exist $Q, a$ such that $y(x) = Q x + a$ because making $u = x_1-x_2$ and $x = x_2$

$$ || y(x+u) - y(x) || = ||u ||$$

and then

$$ || Q(x+u) - Q x || = ||Q u || = ||u||$$

as for instance $Q = I$ or any rotation matrix because if $R$ is a rotation then $||R u|| = ||u||$ and finally

$$
y(x) = R x + a
$$